Why is my differential equation for mass-spring-damper model not converging with ode45 in MATLAB?
I am trying to simulate an electronical device that can be modeled by a mass-spring-damper system with an additional non-linear force. The equation at the equilibrium for the system is the following :
$$
 \frac{\epsilon_0 a V^2}{2 x^2} - Bx' + Kx = 0
$$
The goal of my MATLAB code is to solve this equation for $x$ and find the equilibrium. For this purpose, I use the ode45 function like this (all coefficient are defined in my code but not shown here) :
x0 = 0;
[t, x] = ode45(@(t, x) odefun(t, x, eps0, a, V0, B, d0, K), tspan, x0);

function dxdt = odefun(t, x, eps, a, V, B, d0, K)
    dxdt = ((eps * a * V^2) ./ (2 * B * (d0 - x).^2)) + ((K / B) .* x);
end

The equation is good according to my teachers and several papers but the solver never converges and I can't see why. All coefficient are defined according to the dimensions of a capacitive micromachined ultrasound transducer. The solution of ode45 is the following :
Result of RK4 solver
This is obviously wrong because the dimensions of a cmut are bellow millimeter.
Can you see any mistakes in the way I use the ode45 solver ?
Full code :
% DIMENSIONS DE LA MEMBRANE
e = 500e-9;                 % epaisseur [m]
r = 20e-6;                  % rayon [m]
d0 = 550e-9;                % epaisseur de cavite [m]
a = pi * r^2;               % surface de la membrane [m^2]

% PARAMETRES MECANIQUES
E = 200e9;                  % module d'Young du SiN [Pa]
nu = 0.25;                  % coefficient de poisson du SiN
eta = 18.5e-6;              % viscosité dynamique de l'air [Pa.s]
p0 = 1e5;                   % pression exterieure [Pa]
rhoSiN = 3170;              % densite du SiN [Kg/m^3]
m = rhoSiN * a * e;         % masse membrane [Kg]
K = (16 * E * e^3) / (3 * (1 - nu^2) * r^2);   % raideur [N/m]
B = (eta * pi * r^2) / e;                      % amortissement [N.s/m]

% PARAMETRES ELECTRIQUES
eps0 = 8.85e-12;            % permittivité diélectrique du vide [F/m]
V0 = 10;                    % tension de polarisation [V]

% Conditions initiales et plage de temps
x0 = 0;
ti = 0; tf = 1e-3;
dt = 1e-6;
tspan = linspace(ti, tf, 1/dt);

% Résolution par RK4
[t, x] = ode45(@(t, x) odefun(t, x, eps0, a, V0, B, d0, K), tspan, x0);

plot(t,x,'-')

function dxdt = odefun(t, x, eps, a, V, B, d0, K)
    dxdt = ((eps * a * V^2) ./ (2 * B * (d0 - x).^2)) + ((K / B) .* x);
end

References :

Y. Wang, L. -M. He, Z. Li, W. Xu and J. Ren, "A computationally efficient nonlinear dynamic model for cMUT based on COMSOL and MATLAB/Simulink"
T. Merrien, A. Boulmé and D. Certon, "Lumped-Parameter Equivalent Circuit Modeling of CMUT Array Elements"


It seems to me that, if all the data are correct, the problem can be solved analytically (but for t very small):


There is more than one differential equation solver than ode45 because ode45, like every solver, works best under certain conditions and poorly in other situations.  The issues are things like fixed step vs variable step, stiff systems vs non-stiff systems, different errors that different solvers accumulate in different ways, ...
People who numerically solve differential equations should get into the habit of examining their results, and trying to figure out if they make sense.  If they don't, there are things to try -- setting the parameters of the integration method you're using differently using odeset (particularly minimum or maximum step size).  A next step would be to change which integration method you use.  When an integrator for non-stiff systems fails, I usually try a stiff integration method, like Gear's stiff, next.
If the differential equation is in the middle of some optimization scheme, a la parameter estimation, choosing a handful of different initial guesses may help you too.

Yes I tried using ode15s which is a stiff solver with a min and max step size and got the same result.

It's not clear to me what the forcing function is. (As I don't speak Matlab). However- physically the capacitive diaphragm solution MUST diverge for sufficiently high applied voltage- this is the collapse condition. The first things I would try are (1) solve the DC applied voltage problem so that you know what value of voltage corresponds to the collapse condition and (2) try to solve for a smaller value of the forcing function, whether it is voltage or applied force.

I have access to the real device and found through testing that the collapse voltage should be around 50V. When trying with a simplier model (without the damping force and with the real dimensions) I find a collapse voltage very close to 50V. The issue seems to come from the damping force.



This is obviously wrong because the dimensions of a cmut are bellow millimeter.

It will help if you look at the scale you want and ignore the large excursion. Stop the plot at 85ns and see what you get until then. This will tell you whether the solver is doing anything useful or not at all.
The non-linear force tends to infinity in the limit as \$x\to (x_0=0)\$. Many solvers will have a problem with that. Try setting \$x_0\$ to a small non-zero value. Say, set \$x_0=\text{1E-6}\$ (1μm).

Yes I already tried this and got the same result. I then tried to modify the 1/x^2 into a 1/(d0-x)^2 with d0 being the initial position of the membrane (~500 nm above the bulk) and also got the same result on the plot.
